# Installing mediainfo

Tags: linux, centos6, mediainfo

How i can install mediainfo into my centos6 using wget command?

i tried those commands but i get errors:

```
wget http://mediaarea.net/download/binary/mediainfo-gui/0.7.71/mediainfo-gui-0.7.71-1.x86_64.RHEL_6.rpm
wget http://mediaarea.net/download/binary/mediainfo/0.7.71/mediainfo-0.7.71-1.x86_64.RHEL_6.rpm
wget http://mediaarea.net/download/binary/libmediainfo0/0.7.71/libmediainfo0-0.7.71-1.x86_64.RHEL_6.rpm

rpm -ivh mediainfo-gui-0.7.71-1.x86_64.RHEL_6.rpm
rpm -ivh mediainfo-0.7.71-1.x86_64.RHEL_6.rpm
rpm -ivh libmediainfo0-0.7.71-1.x86_64.RHEL_6.rpm
```

What i have done wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Those RPMs are in the EPEL repo for CentOS. You'd be better off using them:

```
# yum --enablerepo extras install epel-release
# yum install mediainfo-gui mediainfo libmediainfo
```

Comment: I get in second command following error, can you please help.     
No package mediainfo-gui available.
No package mediainfo available.
No package libmediainfo available.
Nothing to do

Comment: I tested the above on an empty, newly created vagrant box - works fine. I don't think I can help any further. Sorry.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/513327/409459 says, there should be a '=' before ```extras```:

```yum --enablerepo=extras install epel-release```